# Verify that joint density satisfies the necessary conditions

Tags: probability

$$f_{XY}(x,y) = \frac{1}{n^2}$$
$$x = 1,2,3,...,n$$
$$y = 1,2,3,...,n$$

I am supposed to verify that $f_{XY}(x,y)$ satisfies the conditions necessary to be a density. As far as I'm concerned these are:

$$f_{XY}(x,y) \geq 0$$
$$\sum _{all\space x}\:\sum _{all\space y}\:f_{XY}(x,y) = 1 $$

The first is pretty obvious in this case. However I can't seem to be able to prove the second one. Could someone explain this in an algebraic point of view?

Thanks!

Comment: How is this a density? It is a discrete distribution.

Comment: Can you find $\sum_{x=1}^n\sum_{y=1}^nc$ where $c$ is a constant? Btw, as @StubbornAtom noticed you are not dealing with a probability density function but with a probability mass function.

Comment: @drhab Oh, yeah sorry. I've just begun learning probability and keep mixing those two up.

Comment: Then this is a nice "moment of learning". Good luck with your study on probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$ is independent of $(x,y)$. One can think of $f_{(X,Y)}$ as the uniform distribution on the product set $\lbrace 1, \ldots, n \rbrace \times \lbrace 1,\ldots, n \rbrace$. It follows that :

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x=1}^{n} \sum_{y=1}^{n} f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) & = \sum_{x=1}^{n} \sum_{y=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^2} \\[2mm]
 & = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{x=1}^{n} \sum_{y=1}^{n} 1 \\[2mm]
 & = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{x=1}^{n} n \\[2mm]
 & = \frac{n^2}{n^2} \\[2mm]
 & = 1.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you this was very good! :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it, your joint density (actually, a discrete mass distribution) $f_{XY}$ is constant. 
The summation $$ \sum_{all \, x} \sum_{all \, y} f_{XY}$$ boils then down to 
$$f_{XY} \sum_{all \, x} \sum_{all \, y} 1  = \frac{1}{n^2} n \cdot n = 1$$